# Question about Vue 3 + TypeScript and Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Does anyone know of a working example of how the type augmentation should be implemented with Vue3 and TypeScript? I have been trying follow the Vue2 docs in hoops of using the same in Vue3 with no success and spend the past 3 hours of searching without any results.

It seems that the `Vue` object in the `vue-class-component` module should be augmented to work,but how?

My implementation is similar to the following:

Any advice?

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins

```
import { App, Plugin } from "vue";

export interface IHelloModule {
  sayHello: (name: string) => string;
}

export const helloPlugin: Plugin = (app: App, options) => {

  const helloModule:IHelloModule = {

    sayHello: function(name: string) {
      return `Hello ${name}`;
    }

  };

  app.provide("$hello", helloModule);
};
```

```
import { Vue } from 'vue-class-component';
import { IHelloModule } from "@/hello";

declare module "vue/types/vue" {
  interface Vue {
    $hello: IHelloModule;
  }
}

declare module "vue/types/vue" {
  interface VueConstructor {
    $auth: IHelloModule;
  }
}
```

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
     .....
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from 'vue-class-component';

@Options({
  components: {
  },
})
export default class Home extends Vue {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$hello.sayHello("World"))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                     Neither TS nor vue-cli recognize this
  }
}
</script>
```

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import { helloPlugin } from "./hello";
import router from "./router";

createApp(App)
  .use(router, helloPlugin)
  .mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For what I understand, `vue-class-component` doesn't fully supports Vue 3 yet. They're still [discussing](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/406) modifications in the library. So, I don't know if the examples below will work with it, but this is what I've done to augment plugin types.

hello.plugin.ts

```
import { App } from "vue";

export interface IHelloModule {
  sayHello: (name: string) => string;
}

export default {
  install: (app: App) => {
    const helloModule: IHelloModule = {
      sayHello: function(name: string) {
        return `Hello ${name}`;
      }
    }; 

    app.config.globalProperties.$hello = helloModule;
  }
}

declare module "@vue/runtime-core" {
  //Bind to `this` keyword
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $hello: IHelloModule;
  }
}
```

I declared the type in the plugin file itself, but you can declare them in the `shims-vue.d.ts` file too.

main.ts

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import Hello from "./hello.plugin";

createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .use(Hello)
  .mount("#app");
```

Hello.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

const Hello = defineComponent({
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$hello.sayHello("World"));
  }
});

export default Hello;
</script>
```

Comment: I used one of the CLI templates and the component `HelloWorld` is written as so: `class HelloWorld extends Vue { msg!: string; }`. Inside, I define the `mounted` function and the compiler throws the error that the $ variable (`$hello` from your example) doesn't exist on the `this` keyword. I'm new to Vue so I'm not sure what I'm missing and I haven't found too many resources for Vue + TS + plugins.

Comment: @RodrigoGomez-Palacio Sorry, didn't see your comment earlier. Maybe it's because you're using a class component instead of a function component? I'm not working with Vue anymore, but for what I remember it's recommended to use defineComponent with Vue 3 + TS.

Comment: How would you automatically declare multiple plugins?