# Vue3 Typescript declaration file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue3 plugin in js, like that:

```
const myPlugin = {
    install(Vue, config) {
           // do something
    }
export default myPlugin;
```

It is in index.js, and will be invoked by app.use.
For TS projects I need to create a type declaration. I found vue/types/plugin in the vue package with an interface for the object and a type for the install method. However I have no clue how to apply this to my plugin.
What needsto  be inside the d.ts file so the typescript compiler knows that myPlugin is supposed to be of type PluginObject?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question about Vue 3 + TypeScript and Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64118679/question-about-vue-3-typescript-and-augmenting-types-for-use-with-plugins)

Comment: In parts yes, but it lacks the information on how to augment plugin options. Image that hello Plugin there had a config object like the one in my simple example above, how do I augment that config object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Vue 3.1.1, `App.use()` allows the `options` argument to be `any`, which seems to prevent augmenting its type declaration. That is, this module augmentation does not override the original `App.use()` (perhaps because `any` supercedes `MyPluginOptions`):

```js
declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface App {
    use(plugin: MyPlugin, ...options: MyPluginOptions[]): this;
  }
}
```

It seems the only current workaround is to edit `node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.d.ts` directly, adding a generic to `Plugin_2` and `PluginInstallFunction` to enable typing the `options` argument:

```js
declare type Plugin_2<Option = any> = PluginInstallFunction<Option> & {
    install?: PluginInstallFunction<Option>;
} | {
    install: PluginInstallFunction<Option>;
};
export { Plugin_2 as Plugin }

declare type PluginInstallFunction<Option> = (app: App, ...options: Option[]) => any;
```

And then replacing the current `App.use()` with:

```js
export declare interface App<HostElement = any> {
    use<Option>(plugin: Plugin_2<Option>, ...options: Option[]): this;
}
```

[demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhFgCgAIWgVAngBwKbQCaoMYBsCGATvgC4CWA9gHYDOUswUWeR6JK6ACrgK4DmZKgH0ATAB4A8snLVoAXmj4qiAHzzo3foICStEvly4AYjyrYZVSdMpU1AMmgBvetFeCa+wwH4AXBt4CVLoeBsam5jZWFioA3FAAvtAAPk4ubnqhfpqBwZ5hZhZRNrEJcZCoAB7IFIQkTv5awiKKNA2B0PFQTDgEhGwcbToZhiYFkVLR6gAU+MjIfgCCcwA00AB0GxTW1DR+EzYA2gC6AJTyakqIZd0sfdCCJKiEAGb42OhLyKkw0MDAPDRUFNkAFBFlQU1Vhs1lsLLtFMpjic-CQABZkGgxX7AaBojHQXCCdAUABuT0IZCwrQARqhcBQAO7QKa07D4AHE54IxAnFwcorUFTAiHgxqiAW2KGbba0PYypEo9GYhJdSCgCAwODZQT0ECMSDsNCDKgLfbUJBGhTOH6wmwARl80A8FKofDKrlt1BEfioPAAtrTCO7oJ6qABmPzUigUXCoJRlTqQKDYHZ1bUm9TW9IhQwzOaLFbraVw0WBU0yi2oJHfFyJxPJ1PGgBCmZc7jyefm0E+Z2ttZVSbVYF10AAsvgdZr9Sm9Io5pnEvhWp9VbNkC41hypumFqtHCGZRHcYQeOh4mc-tBADLkB4szSmfQAjjwyH0MGc-RiaII+Butzu93PbFr1vGxmiUDBQOoMNmSfF83w-L8fz-QFtwhBYLxxQBQchQoEAPqUNvWgO1VlDI8SBPM9MOgHCfk3VD8P3UM7T8AByZ5o1Y0iZSIkioPDFFKI6ajaNcXC0MaJsRPE9Mm0A6ib1MSo0HMVBIJBRp+KAA)

I also submitted a [PR to `vue-next`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/pull/3969). If it gets merged, you wouldn't need module augmentation, as the `options` type would be automatically inferred.