# Augmenting Types for Use with Plugins for Vue 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

At first: I'm aware that there is an similar issue ([Question about Vue 3 + TypeScript and Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64118679/question-about-vue-3-typescript-and-augmenting-types-for-use-with-plugins)) but it was closed erroneously.

For Vue 2 there is an entry in the documentation for using plugins together with typescript: [Augmenting Types for Use with Plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins), but for **Vue 3** isn't.

To sum up, what I want to achieve: I want to use my plugin as `this.$my-plugin()` in a components `defineComponent()` but I'm getting the error `Property '$my-plugin' does not exist on type 'ComponentPublicInstance[...]` when I follow the guide for Vue 2. So I assume the syntax for the `.d.ts` file must be changed. My current file:

```js
import { Vue } from 'vue';

import MyPlugin from './my-plugin';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface Vue {
        $my-plugin: MyPlugin
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `main.ts` add `ComponentCustomProperties` inside `'@vue/runtime-core'` module:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import MyPlugin from './my-plugin';
...

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties  {
     $myPlugin: MyPlugin //don't use kebab-case as key in js
     }
   }
let app=createApp(App)
app.config.globalProperties.$myPlugin= MyPlugin ;

app.mount('#app')
```